# Including other Python file in current project

Tags: python

I have the following file. It contains several functions that I would use frequently. Instead of writing the same function over and over in every project, I think it would be more efficient if we are able to include the files in each project.

I want to include functions inside this file:

[image]

However, I don't know what technique is called and I am not sure if it is possible to make it work.

`tools` is not found:

[image]

Here's the folder that I want to include:

[image]

I have created `__init__.py` as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116384/17869806

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Jupyter notebook, create a new one in the folder ivm_github_python with this content:

```
from tools import ivm_string_print
ivm_string_print.myfunction()
```

in this case `myfunction` is defined in `ivm_string_print.py`

Comment: it is working after i add `sys.path.append('/Users/inetvmart/Documents/GitHub/ivm_github_python/tools/')`

Answer (score 1):

So in the file which is the main file for each project you can do
`import filename` and import it as a module in the start of the project.

**Note:** the file which you want to import should be in the same folder as your main file. and suppose the file name you want to import is *"functions.py"*
when you import it write `import functions` and not `import functions.py`

*pls upvote if helps :)*